# Changing dual supply to single supply for the following circuit

Tags: transistors, amplifier, dual-supply

The following circuit has a +-15V supply.  What will be the circuit modifications (only in the final stage the driver and the power amplifier) if I want to use a single voltage source with a ground reference 0V like +9V or +15V or in this case +30V?

[image]

Comment: As demonstrated in my [answer to your previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/601524/class-ab-power-amplifier-from-electronic-devices-by-thomas-l-floyd/601527#601527), that circuit is faulty and needs a resistor and capacitor. Hence, carrying through the faulty circuit to a new question is going to cause problems.

Comment: I see you've changed the circuit pictorially but, it's still the same old faulty circuit it always was. Have you tried simulation?

Comment: Yes I have tried and the output signal is clipped on both sides upper and lower side

Comment: I just want a demo that how will be the circuit with only a single supply

Comment: You need to resolve this problem first before using a bad circuit on a single supply. I mean, what's the point; it won't fix itself on a single supply. Fix the circuit. Maybe, before someone tries to answer this question you show the simulated circuit and the clipping i.e. dump the current question until you have a circuit that works.